# Action Class with Junit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

In what class should I write:
 `Actions actions = new Actions(driver);` ?

I don't want actions to be hard-coded. This is how my PageObjects looks like, here I want to use Actions Class

```
package Selenium;

import java.rmi.activation.ActivationSystem;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class internetPO extends basicPageObject {



GenericWebElement wd;


public internetPO(GenericWebElement remotewebdriver){
    this.wd=remotewebdriver;  
}
   public void hover(){
   Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   WebElement ss= wd.element(byTypes.XPATH, finalElements.profileHover);
    actions.moveToElement(ss).perform();
     WebElement ww = wd.element(byTypes.XPATH, finalElements.profilename);

     String valid = ww.getText();
     System.out.println(valid);
}
```

And this is my TestClass:

```
package Selenium;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestName;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class baseTest  {

GenericWebElement wd;
public WebDriver webdriver;

public internetPO inter;

@Rule
public TestName name = new TestName();
public TestWatcher log = new TestWatcher() {

};

public void Testname(Description testname){
    System.out.println("Starting test" + testname.getMethodName());

}

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception{
    String Testname = name.getMethodName();
    System.out.println("Strting test " + Testname);

    wd=new ChromeWebDriver();


    wd.init("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");    

     inter = new internetPO(wd);
   }
```

Need to mention I'm using RemoteWebDriver in GenericWebElement class.
I tried a lot of options but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I did in my project is that I created a class as CustomActions which needs a Webdriver object for construction:

```
package utils.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

class CustomActions{

    private static final String JS_SCROLL_TO_TOP_PAGE = "scrollTo(0, 0)";
    private static final String JS_MOUSE_SCROLL_DRAFT = "scroll(%s, %s)";

    private Actions actions;
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    CustomActions(WebDriver driver) {
        this.webDriver = driver;
        this.actions = new Actions(this.webDriver);
    }

    void jsExecuteScript(String text){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) this.webDriver).executeScript(text);
    }

    void goToTopPage() {
         this.jsExecuteScript(JS_SCROLL_TO_TOP_PAGE);
    }

    void scroll(int horizontal, int vertical) {
        this.jsExecuteScript(String.format(JS_MOUSE_SCROLL_DRAFT, String.valueOf(horizontal), String.valueOf(vertical)));
    }

    void dragAndDropBy(WebElement element, int horizontal, int vertical) {
        this.actions.dragAndDropBy(element, horizontal, vertical).build().perform();
    }

}
```

So you can wrap any actions that you need here. Then in your driver class:

```
package utils.selenium;

public final class Driver {
    private static final long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 100;
    private static final long DEFAULT_SHORT_TIMEOUT = 1;

    private static Driver wrappedDriver;
    private static WebDriver webDriver;
    private Waiter waiter;
    private CustomActions customActions;

    private Driver(WebDriver driver) {
        this.waiter = new Waiter(driver);
        this.customActions = new CustomActions(driver);

        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    ...// many other required things
    // Then your required actions:
    public void scrollToTopOfThePage() {
        customActions.goToTopPage();
    }

    public void scrollMouse(int horizontal, int vertical) {
        customActions.scroll(horizontal, vertical);
    }

    public void executeCustomJS(String js) {
        customActions.jsExecuteScript(js);
    }

    public void dragAndDropBy(WebElement element, int horizontal, int vertical) {
        customActions.dragAndDropBy(element, horizontal, vertical);
    }
}
```

It was just an idea that I used in my codes and I hope it gives you a good idea. Actually your question is really nice and I hope a more expert user comes here with a perfect answer. Good luck!